# Is training a tree faster with squared-error loss as compared to other losses?

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, cart, boosting

I am reading through various introductions to decision trees and boosting algorithms. It strikes me that people always like to resort to squared-error loss whenever a tree needs to be trained. For example, gradient boosting allows any loss function to be minimized but operationally it only trains trees with squared-error loss (when fitting trees to gradients).

So I am wondering whether training a tree is simpler with a squared-error loss as compared to other loss functions? I have been trying to find an answer in various books but have found no explicit answer. My guess is that under the squared-error loss, there is some shortcut for finding the split point (Basically, you only need to make the means of the two split leaves as far apart as possible).

With a general loss function (e.g., binomial), there seems to be no similar trick to find the optimal split.

Can someone confirm this or point me to a different reason?

Comment: Can you please clarify the statement: "*it only trains trees with squared-error loss (when fitting trees to gradients)*" a bit more? It is twice-differentiable losses function we care about so we can do Newton steps. That said, depending on the implementation we might have different ways of growing a tree (for example, LightGBM by default grows trees leaf-wise and [chooses the leaf with max delta loss to grow](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Features.html), while CatBoost grows [symmetric trees](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/parameter-tuning.html#tree-growing-policy)).

Comment: Let me try my best. The algorithm I read is from Hastie & Tibshirani. In each iteration of boosting, you basically compute the gradient of the loss function at each observation, then grow a shallow tree to fit these gradients, with squared-error loss function.

Comment: As you mentioned in a comment, evaluating minima for _all_ possible splits for other losses might take more that $O(N)$. I don't know if Huber can be dealt with in this time, but the quadratic loss can: enumerating all data (or bins if histograms) is unavoidable, but luckily we know that the optimal _prediction_ for each leave is the mean, which is why we keep $O(N)$. Also, asymptotic complexity is not everything: engineering challenges come in the way. For example, Gini is used in place of cross-entropy, because the logarithm is not a very simple function for hardware.

Comment: Even if there were potential benefits of using a more complex loss at each boosting iteration, the question is whether these benefits cannot be offset by simply increasing the number of iterations. And I believe this is why quadratic loss is used in boosted trees' iterations.

Comment: Pages 357--358 of Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman's "Elements of statistical learning" contain a condensed summary of reasons for using the quadratic loss is used, which were already mentioned here.

Comment: @paperskilltrees, which edition of HTF's book are you referring to?

Comment: @maxsim Second edition,12th printing, https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/download.html

Comment: @paperskilltrees, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My (limited) understanding is that you can make finding the best-variance split into an $O\left( N \right)$ operation.

*Note: You are asking about variance, which applies to continuous variables, and not something like gini score (aka not gini coefficient) which is used for categorical ones.*

**Setup:**
Lets say you have a the following case:

```
library(pracma)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
x <- linspace(x1=0,x2=1,n=101)
y <- rep.int(x = 1, times = 101)
y[50:101] <- 2
y <- y + rnorm(n = 101, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +geom_path()
```

aka

[image]

The eyeball says "split at x=0.5".  It is a toy, not 1000 dimensions, or 1M rows.

**The classic way:**
To compute the group variance we need to first compute the mean by $N$ additions, lets assume we have a decent memory structure so we don't have to increment rows, then we need a divide at the end.  We then subtract the mean from each element and square it for an additional $2N$ times and at the end divide again.  This gives $3N+2$ operations to get the total variance.  If we perform $N$ operations for $N$ times it is an $O\left( N^2 \right)$ total operations.

**An alternative form:**
The windowed mean, also known as rolling subgroup mean, can be made to look like EWMA.

$$ \mu_{N} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i} $$
$$ \mu_{N} =  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}{x_i} + \frac{1}{N} x_{N}$$

$$ \mu_{N} = \frac{N-1}{N} \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}{x_i} + \frac{1}{N} x_{N}$$
$$ \mu_{N} = \frac{N-1}{N} \mu_{N-1} + \frac{1}{N} x_{N}$$
$$ \mu_{N} = \left(1-\alpha \right) \cdot \mu_{N-1} + \alpha \cdot x_{N}$$

Similarly with the variance.  Feel free to work out how the running variance is computed using a running mean.

This means we can compute the change in variance of the split by having a pair of rolling windows, one at the start and one at the end, so for about $8N$ which is $ O\left(N \right)$.

**Applying it:**
Here is a graphical example of it:

```
N <- nrow(df)
var_all <- var(y)

store1 <- numeric(length = N);store2 <- numeric(length = N);store3 <- numeric(length = N)

mu1  <- y[1]
var1 <- 0.5*var(y[1:2])

for(i in 2:N){
  
  #first mean
  mu1  <- ((i-1)/i)*mu1 + (1/i)*y[i]
  var1 <- ((i-1)/i)*var1 + (1/i)*(y[i]-mu1)^2
  
  store1[i] <- var1
  store2[i] <- var(y[i:N])
  
}

store2[1] <- var_all
store1[N] <- var_all
store2[N] <- store1[1]

df2 <- data.frame(x=x,y=y, 
                  v1=store1, v2=store2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_path(aes(y=v1), color="Red")+
  geom_path(aes(y=v2), color="Blue") +
  geom_path(aes(y=v1+v2), color="darkgreen", size=1)+
  ylab("Variance") +
  xlab("Split location")
```

Which yields this:

[image]

You can see the very clear minimum variance in the middle.

A challenge for you, replace the "var" part of "store2[i] <- var(y[i:N])" with the rolling mean and variance, and get the same plot. Hint: it will require its own for loop, and be careful about start/end conditions.

Comment: Thanks much. To make sure I understand properly, you are saying with squared-error loss the split can be done in O(N), but with a loss like Huber or absolute-error, it will be O(N^2)?

Comment: Lots of folks don’t even ask about that kind of error. I was thinking that you were asking in terms of things like Gini, which is a clear categorical loss associated with the tree. I could see it also being contrast against some thing like Cohens kappa, Because Cohen’s kappa is also about categorical.